# iOS 8 third-party keyboard for accentuated characters?

Tags: keyboard, ios

iOS 8 now supports third-party keyboards. I am pretty satisfied with Apple's default keyboard, however one thing is a hassle for me, as a French speaker : typing accentuated characters takes a **long** time, because you first have to touch for instance the letter "E" and then wait for the accentuated variants such as "é è ë..." to appear.

Hence my question : is there a third-party keyboard especially designed for quickly typing accentuated characters ?

Comment: I think it's just a matter of time.  So far I have seen them for Kannada, Malayalam, Tamil, Telugu, and Georgian.  Someone will do French, German, Swedish, etc pretty soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 8 (like iOS 7) on my iPad has a French keyboard called Accented AZERTY, where you type é by typing e and then the accent from the bottom row of keys.  This is a lot faster than holding down the e key for most people.

Comment: Thanks, it does 95% of what I need. A dedicated French keyboard (with accents) might however be ultimately better, especially on bigger screens (iPad or iPhone 6).

Answer (score 0):

My first post, so my apologies if it’s simplistic.
Settings>General>keyboard>text replacement. My volume of need is prob way less than yours. Two of my top hits are the definition of résumé is resumee, the definition for vis-à-vis is viss. I repeat the last letter since my finger/thumb is already hovering. Lastly, I also use a modification of this for fractions e.g. ½ is defined as 1//2.